# Can-bus data has some bits always set to 0

Tags: embedded-linux, loopback, can-bus

I'm setting up the CAN-bus on a new custom board. It uses the mcp2515 controller connected via SPI-Bus. When receiving using 'candump' one bit in the data is always 0 (to be specific, the first bit off the data). The two other devices on the bus work perfectly.
 Possibly related, there is a timing problem in the hardware, I have to set the baud-rate 20% higher to get the correct baud rate for the other devices.

This even happens if I disconnect the bus-cable and enable loopback!

```
#ip link set can0 type can bitrate 600000 loopback on
#ifconfig can0 up
#candump can0 &
# cansend can0 0FF#AABBCCDDEEFFFFFF
  can0  4FB   [8]  2A BB CC DD EE FF FF FF
  can0  0FF   [8]  AA BB CC DD EE FF FF FF
# cansend can0 0AB#AABBCCDDEEFFFFFF
  can0  4AB   [8]  2A BB CC DD EE FF FF FF
  can0  0AB   [8]  AA BB CC DD EE FF FF FF
# cansend can0 000#0000CCDDEEFFFFFF
  can0  400   [8]  00 00 4C DD EE FF FF FF
  can0  000   [8]  00 00 CC DD EE FF FF FF
```

Are there any obvious reasons why this could be happening?
Is it possible the timing error in the hardware causes this problem, even in loopback mode?

*edit*
removed example with a bad CAN_ID 'FFF' to reduce confusion

Comment: Do you mean that when you send 0xfff you get 0x7ff on the other side? You send standard frames and their [ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Base_frame_format) length is 11 bits. So 0x7ff is the max value.

Comment: @yegorich  Good point, I added some more examples. It seems it's always with the first bit of the ID and Data

Comment: Hm.. looks really strange. I'd ask this question on the [linux-can mailinglist](http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html#linux-can). Also provide your hardware arch/model, kernel version, Linux distribution, can-utils version etc.

Comment: 600kbps isn't a standard CAN baudrate. Most likely the target doesn't support it. Still, you shouldn't get data corruptions because the CRC check would catch those. So my best guess is that this is your diagnostic tool being bad when it spots bit stuffing or something like that.

Comment: What is `FFF#FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` supposed to mean, given 11 bit identifier?

Comment: Identifier FFF is my mistake, I'll remove it from the example to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find solution to both problems:

- The crystal was defines as 24 MHz but there was a 20 MHz build in. That explains, why I needed a 20% higher baud-rate to communicate.
- The SPI-Bus had a wrong max-frequency. Somehow some of the first recieved ones where zero when reading the bus. With the correct settings the can-bus now works perfectly.